# Add a new state to a User Story in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to add a new state to the user story Work Item type in VSTS. To do this I follow the instructions outlined here:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/docs/work/process/customize-process-workflow

However, when I get the states page the "+ New state" option is greyed out and I cannot click on it.  I am a member of the "Project Collection Administrators".

Can anyone tell me how to enable the "+ New state" button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So VSO has this Hierarchy like there are Processes which can be considered as your SDLC ( Agile, CMMI and Scrum). These are System defined processes and we cannot edit them. And Each Process can have many number of Work Items associated with it. System level process cannot be edited meaning you cannot create, edit, create state for a system process. The work around is to create a Inherited Process with the Available System Processes, which will also inherit the Work Items. This inherited process can be edited (you can create, edit, create state for the work items available in this inherited process). So keep in mind while inheriting from any process, for which work work item you want to add state and create a inherited process from that parent process.

Please follow this link to create a inherited process : https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/process/manage-process

Also keep in mind that whatever project you create has to be based on the inherited process so that the changes that you make in the customization is available at the Work Item form level. 
Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Bhadhri

Comment: Creating an inherited process fixed the problem thanks.

Comment: Happy to Help :)